# Counter for selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have series of dropdown list with options 'Present', 'Absent', 'Expelled' and  'V.H'. I want to set a counter for 'Total', 'Present', 'Absent', 'Expelled' and  'V.H'. Initially all students are assumed to be present. If there are 100 students, then initially the counter should look like 
Total: 100
Present: 100
Absent: 0
Expelled: 0
V.H: 0

If I change one dropdown from Prsent to Absent, then the counter should like
 Total: 100
Present: 99
Absent: 1
Expelled: 0
V.H: 0

and so on.

How to make it effect? I think javascript or jquery can serve the purpose. Part of my code is given below

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.abs{background-color:yellow}
.exp{background-color:red}
</style>

<?php echo "<select id='dd1{$no}' name='dd1[$no]'  onchange='this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className' ><option  class='pre'>Present</option><option class='abs'>Absent</option><option   class='exp'>Expelled</option><option>V.H.</option></select>";?>

</html>
```

I have tried it in the following way

```
<html>
<head> <script src="jq/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<style>

#cnt{ position: fixed; top: 10; left: 10; background: #fff; }
</style>
<script>
var precount = 100;
var abscount = 0;

$(".abs").on('click', function () {
abscount++;
precount--;

});

$(".pre").on('click', function () {
precount++;
abscount--;

});   
document.getElementById("pre1").value = precount;
document.getElementById("abs1").value = abscount;
</script> 

</head>

<table id="cnt">
<tr><td>Total</td><td><input type="text" size="2" id=""></td></tr>
<tr><td>Present</td><td><input type="text" size="2" id="pre1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Absent</td><td><input type="text" size="2" id="abs1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Expelled</td><td><input type="text" size="2" id=""></td></tr>

</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `click` event on `<option>`s doesn't fire in all browsers, due to the way select boxes can be implemented as native window widgets.

In any case it wouldn't be reliable, as you could click on an `abs` that was already selected and increase the `abscount` when the number of selected `abs`s had not changed.

Instead, try to recalculate the calculated fields from scratch every time any of them change. For example:

```
function calculateTotals() {
   var valueCounts = {pre: 0, abs: 0, exp: 0, vh: 0};
   $('.presence').each(function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
       valueCounts[value] += 1;
   });

   $('#pre-count').val(valueCounts.pre);
   $('#abs-count').val(valueCounts.abs); // ...
}

$('.presence').on('change', calculateTotals);
calculateTotals();

...

<select class="presence">
    <option value="pre">Present</option>
    <!-- ... -->
</select>

<input type="text" id="pre-count" readonly>
<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var precount = 100;
var abscount = 0;

$(".abs").on('click', function () {
precount=document.getElementById("pre1").value ;
abscount=document.getElementById("abs1").value  ;
abscount=parseInt(abscount)+1;
precount=parseInt(precount)-1;
document.getElementById("pre1").value = precount;
document.getElementById("abs1").value = abscount;
});

$(".pre").on('click', function () {
precount=document.getElementById("pre1").value ;
abscount=document.getElementById("abs1").value  ;
precount=parseInt(precount)+1;
abscount=parseInt(abscount)-1;
document.getElementById("pre1").value = precount;
document.getElementById("abs1").value = abscount;
});   
document.getElementById("pre1").value = precount;
document.getElementById("abs1").value = abscount;
</script>
```